# Alternatives for MySql LIMIT 1 clause - do not want to be limitted to one RDBMS

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am currently working with MySQL. It is important for me not to write any SQL statements in my C# program that cannot translate to SQL Server.

Is there any other query I can make that will limit the result of a SELECT statement to 1 result?

My intention is to:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.column = (SELECT somecolumn FROM table2 WHERE somestuff LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Are you aware that `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` cause your update will get random data? `LIMIT`/`TOP` is not solution for your problem, you need to rethink query. In SQL Server you can use `SELECT TOP 1 somecolumn FROM table2 WHERE ...`

Comment: Yes, I am. The SELECT statement in my case could return 2 or 3 results but it doesn't matter which one is the value that is being set.

Comment: So use `UPDATE table1 
SET table1.column = (SELECT DISTINCT somecolumn FROM table2 WHERE somestuff);` then, if somecolumn is the same

Comment: @lad2025 . . . The update does not get *random* data.  It gets data from an indeterminate row, that can change from execution to execution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That what I mean, this will be nondeterministic, depending of plan I can get different result so to end user data will be random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care which is being set, then  use `max()` or `min()`:

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET table1.column = (SELECT MIN(somecolumn) FROM table2 WHERE somestuff);
```

This is ANSI standard SQL and should work in any database.

I do caution you that the intersection between MySQL and SQL Server functionality is rather thin, leaving out a whole range of functions on dates and strings, and important query functionality such as ranking functions, full outer join, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, you are trying to write generic application such that same queries will work across board. If that's correct understanding, you are probably on wrong track. You would not be able to do that unless all of your applicatio's scope is limited to just one query. Essentially all databases support different formats of queries, and though most of them near to each other doesn't mean you have to write generic queries. There are plenty of good implementations with repository patterns for example [this one though XML but idea is similar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271610/how-to-implement-the-repository-pattern-for-an-app-that-will-change-its-database%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653453/repository-pattern-switch-out-the-database-and-switch-in-xml-files%20this) or [even this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271610/how-to-implement-the-repository-pattern-for-an-app-that-will-change-its-database). Read up on these and implement on of such implementations instead of chasing down generic commands